# Storing user ID to session during payment sequence, is this safe? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

Users are able to purchase products without an account. However, after they have purchased the product they must create an account to access the product. Their email is entered into a stripe form during registration, as I am using stripe for payments. In the back-end I am creating an account for the user post-purchase like this:

```
 $newUser = new User;
 $newUser->email = $request->stripeEmail;
```

Next, I am storing the user's ID to session.

```
Session::put('id', $user->id);
```

The user is then redirected to a page to fill out further information, here, I am retrieving the user's ID from the session and finishing off their account.

```
 $id = Session::get('id');
 $user = User::where('id',$id)->first();
 // add details to user submitted from form
```

Obviously, since I am dealing with payments I want to be as careful as possible. Is this method of storing the user's ID for completion at a later stage entirely safe?

Comment: Nothing is "entirely safe", but since this is a user-id that is not even used yet (before the user has filled out the information), it's fairly innocuous. Granted, if someone got hold of the information, and were able to hijack the session, they would be able to fill in the user information, and get access to the account. The chances of that happening is fairly slim, but it IS a possiblity, however it's a possibility that will always be there. It's fairly normal to store an ID / user-id in the session.

Comment: Yes. Generally speaking, session data is considered safe. Unlike raw cookies, session data can only be set/changed on the back-end. Clients cannot spoof session data. But session ID (which is usually stored in cookies) can be hijacked (by techniques that are beyond the scope of this question). Be sure at least to use HTTPS.